# Implementing seq2seq Model With Beam Search in Tensorflow 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to create a seq2seq model using beam search. The problem that I am having is that I can not find a guide on how to implement beam search into my decoder using TensorFlow.

### Background

By using a seq2seq model is to be able to convert handwritten math formulas into latex code. I have followed [this](https://guillaumegenthial.github.io/image-to-latex.html) tutorial but it was written with an older version of Tensorflow and I am not entirely familiar with it.

I know that this problem is fairly similar to the image captioning problem. So I thought a good place to start was to implement the same pipeline from [this Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning) into the image to latex problem.

### Current Approach

My current approach is the following

```py
class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim, units, vocab_size):
        super(Decoder, self). __init__()
        self.units = units

        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.units,
                                    return_sequences=True,
                                    return_state=True,
                                    recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
        self.fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.units)
        self.fc2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

        self.attention = BahdanauAttention(self.units)

    def call(self, x, features, hidden):
        # defining attention as a separate model
        context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(features, hidden)

        # x shape after passing through embedding == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim)
        x = self.embedding(x)

        # x shape after concatenation == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim + hidden_size)
        x = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1), x], axis=-1)

        # passing the concatenated vector to the GRU
        output, state = self.gru(x)

        # shape == (batch_size, max_length, hidden_size)
        x = self.fc1(output)

        # x shape == (batch_size * max_length, hidden_size)
        x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, x.shape[2]))

        # output shape == (batch_size * max_length, vocab)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        return x, state, attention_weights

    def reset_state(self, batch_size):
        return tf.zeros((batch_size, self.units))
```

Thanks for the help!